# Aligning links side by side (JSFiddle)

Tags: css, asp.net

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frayt/hj78hg25/2/

I'm trying to get the "Favourite","0" and "Reply" elements to align side by side so they read like:

`Favourite 0 Reply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to not give each of the elements it's own `<h>` tag:

```
        <h5>
        <a class ="not-bold lower-links">Favourite</a>
        0
        <a href="#" class ="not-bold lower-links">Reply</a>
        </h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your h5's containing the "0" and "Reply" must be `display:inline`

```
display:inline
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp